# json_encode returning the next rows values - PHP PDO SQL HighCharts

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, highcharts

When trying to use json_encode from arrays in foreach() the data moves in to the next values, for example:

I have this table which is coming from the same query + php:

[image: Table]

when using json_encode to try and fit this tables data in to highcharts, my outcome is like this:

```
[{"name":"User1","data":[0,2,0,0]},{"name":"User2","data":[0,2,0,0,2,0,2,4]}]
```

So it's moving User1's data in to User2's

My desired outcome would be:

```
[{"name":"User1","data":[0,2,0,0]},{"name":"User2","data":[2,0,2,4]}]
```

This is my code:

```
$uniqueHours = array();
$series = array();
$data = array();

foreach ($pdo->query("SELECT DATEPART(HOUR, AL.EndDateTime) AS 'EndHour'
                    FROM ActivityLog AL
                    WHERE
                    ".$where."
                    ORDER BY AL.EndDateTime, 'EndHour' DESC") as $row)
{

    if ( in_array($row['EndHour'], $uniqueHours) ) {
        continue;
    }
    $uniqueHours[] = $row['EndHour'];
}

$ODsql = "SELECT * FROM Users";
foreach ($pdo->query($ODsql) as $row)
{

    echo '<tr>';

    $SCardNumber   = $row['CardNumber'];
    $SEmployeeName = $row['Username'];

    echo '<td>'.$SEmployeeName.'</td>';

    $chartValues = "";

    foreach($uniqueHours as $hour)
    {

        $countSQL= $pdo->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT(COUNT(AL.TerminalNumber)) AS TOTALS
                FROM ActivityLog AL, WavePick WP
                WHERE AL.TransactionType = 'SPK' AND WP.PickedQty > 0
                AND DATEPART(HOUR, AL.EndDateTime) = ".$hour."
                AND AL.StartDateTime >= '".$StartDate." 00:00:00.000' AND AL.EndDateTime <= '".$StartDate." 23:59:59.000'
                AND AL.OrderNumber = WP.OrderNumber
                AND AL.CardNumber = '".$SCardNumber."'
                ");
        $countSQL->execute();
        $result   = $countSQL->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $row_count = $result->TOTALS;
        $totals[] = $result->TOTALS;

        echo '<td>'.$row_count.'</td>';


    }

    echo '</tr>';

    $series['name'] = $SEmployeeName;
    $series['data'] = $totals;
    array_push($data,$series);

}
```

I haven't actually put this in to the chart yet because the data is invalid.
I am using this to return the outcome:

```
            echo "<div class='well'>";
print json_encode($results, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
echo "</div>";
```

How can I make this data show only for each user it is linked to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before this loop:

```
foreach($uniqueHours as $hour)
```

empty $total array with

```
 $total=array();
 foreach($uniqueHours as $hour)
```